# Can I use coefficients of ridge regression as feature importance values?

Tags: regression, importance, stepwise-regression

If I have normalized all predictors, can I use coefficients of ridge regression as feature importance values? Normalization in my case means:

$(x - u) / s$

where $u$ is the mean and $s$ is the standard deviation. And if I want to reduce the number of predictors, can I do it with backward stepwise regression bypassing features by descending of coefficients?

UPD: For instance, there are predictors $P_1$, $P_2$, ..., $P_{100}$. After normalization they turn into $P_1^{norm}$, $P_2^{norm}$, ..., $P_{100}^{norm}$.
Every $P_i^{norm}$ has got a mean equal to 0 and a standard deviation equal to 1.
Can I say that $P_1^{norm}$ is more important for regression than $P_2^{norm}$, if the absolute value of coefficient $P_1^{norm}$ is greater than the absolute value of coefficient $P_2^{norm}$?
If I want to minimize the number of predictors, can I use the algorithm below?

Backward stepwise regression algorithm:

1. Sort normalized predictors by absolute values of coefficients in ascending order.
2. Loop through predictors removing one predictor in every iteration. After removing some performance metrics are recalculated to decide if it makes sense to continue the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you are trying to model, the purpose of your "feature importance" estimates, why you need to reduce the number of predictors, and how you intend to use the final model. Feature-importance estimates and what's done with them often hurt more than they help. Please provide those details by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thanks, I have been trying to clarify the question.

Comment: The approach of ranking by coefficients of standardize variables does not work in general.  Think about a binary predictor.  The lower its prevalence the more importance it gets.  The reverse should be true.  It is probably better to use the proportion of log likelihood explained or something that approximates that such as an estimate divided by its standard error.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Can you explain your idea in more detail? Or can give a link to some source where it is described?

Comment: The variance of a binary predictor with proportion of ones=p is p(1-p).  Normalization of such predictors is very problematic.